# Saving JTextPane's contents into ordinary text file fails

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextpane

I have following chunk of code:

```
private void saveAs()
{
    CDocument currentDocument=this.panelMain().openedDocuments().get(this.panelMain().openedDocuments().size()-1);
    StyledDocument contents=currentDocument.getStyledDocument();
    DefaultEditorKit kit=new DefaultEditorKit();
    JFileChooser chooserSaveAs=new JFileChooser();

    chooserSaveAs.setDialogTitle("Save as ...");
    if(chooserSaveAs.showSaveDialog(this)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        String strNewFilename=chooserSaveAs.getSelectedFile().getName();
        BufferedOutputStream out;

        try
        {
            out=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(strNewFilename));
            kit.write(out,
                    contents,
                    contents.getStartPosition().getOffset(),
                    contents.getLength());
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException | BadLocationException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(CFrameMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null,
                    ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Once executed, this codes DOES NOT generate any exceptions, but I cannot find saved file on disk anywhere (I've searched through local disk with Total Commander). Why there is no file generated? I am currently working on Windows 7 Ultimate and I tried to save in to logged user's desktop (because of possible access violations problems ...)?

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Could you try to call out.flush(); before closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but I've managed to fix it. I used @Tom's approach and it works! Here is the code chunk:

```
  try
    {
        out=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        kit.write(out,
                  contents,
                  contents.getStartPosition().getOffset(),
                  contents.getLength());
        out.close();
    }
    catch(IOException | BadLocationException ex)
    {
         bError=true;
         Logger.getLogger(CFrameMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                        null,
                        ex);
     }
     finally
     {
          if(bError!=true)
          {
                       currentDocument.setFilename(chooserSaveAs.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                      this.toolBarFileSwitcher().listOpenedFiles().model().set(this.toolBarFileSwitcher().listOpenedFiles().getSelectedIndex(),
                            currentDocument.filename());
                    this.toolBarFileSwitcher().updateUI();
           }
    }
```

Comment: Please learn how to use code formatting.  Select the code sample & click the `{}` button.

Comment: There is no need to use the `updateUI()` method. If you think you need it then you have some other logic error in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Get the File not the name and it should be saved to the right place.

Also you can log out the File's absolute path to see where it is.

```
    File file =chooserSaveAs.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: But the file DOES NOT exists at save time!

Comment: There is no need to shout. Are you saying that you have tried the adjusted code, it wrote out the file's location (even if it didn't exist) and then after the save there was no file there still?